# Failed to register bundle identifier

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, app-store-connect

I need to put the latest version of the app on *AppStoreConnect* to test it on *TestFlight*.
I encounter a problem when archiving the project in order to upload it on *AppStoreConnect* and be able to add a new version of the app and test it on *TestFlight*.
I have been added as a developer in *AppStoreConnect* in the project.
So I added my profile in Xcode with the right email address. During archiving, these two errors appear:

1. > Failed to register bundle identifier: The app identifier "com.xxxxx.app" cannot be registered to your development team because it is not available. Change your bundle identifier to a unique string to try again.`
2. > No profiles for 'com.xxxxx.app' were found: Xcode couldn't find any iOS App Development provisioning profiles matching 'com.xxxxx.app'.`

I confirmed with the project manager the bundleID which is good: "com.xxxxx.app".
Despite several tries and research, I haven't found the solution to this problem, so I can't archive the app so I can add *AppStoreConnect*.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Did you create an App in App Store Connect that also matches the Bundle-ID?

Answer (score 1):

Trying changing Team to just "Your Name" without (personal team) extension.  This is what worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Hey :) when opening preferences for Xcode do you see your company user account?

also when opening the target app underder singing & capabilities, do you see that it is all clear there or is there an error? (you should see that under signing certificate field your account is configured)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, No the project manager asked me for my appleid (so it's a personal email) so I don't have a company account.
In the "TEAM" section there is : "MY NAME (Personal Team).
The project manager then added me as a developer in his project on applestoreconnect.
 And yes these are the only two mistakes I encounter

Answer (score 0):

I think the solution is to change the XXXX in "com.xxxxx.app" to unique value like your name and last name for example : "com.zizou.app".

Comment: That's not an answer to the question

Answer (score 0):

I got this error because I used uppercase in my bundle identifier. Change bundle identifier to all lowercase.